# Python reading dictionary from file

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read a dictionary from a JSON file which would look something like this.

```
{"@C": "C:\\Users\\user\\examplefolder}
```

I would like to load the dictionary from the file into `filepath_dict`. I am currently using this method to try this however, it refuses to load anything that is not a string.

```
import json


with open("filepaths.json", "r") as file:
    file.write(json.loads(filepaths_dict))
```

How can I load the JSON dictionary into a python one?

Comment: I missed the call; Fernando caught it.  It loads only strings, because you called `json.loads` (load string).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `json.load`

```
with open("filepaths.json", "r") as f:
    filepaths_dict = json.load(f)
```

`json.loads`: Will take a string

`json.load`: Will take a file

Also be careful about using the word "file" as a variable, you are overriding the built-in `file` function.

Comment: Thanks very much, I'll accept the answer as soon as I am allowed